# Why when I input a specific number, I get a completely different one?

Tags: c, function, if-statement, int, scanf

So I made a program that checks if a year is a leap year or not.

Here's the code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>



int year[30];


int leapOrNot()
{


    if(*year % 4 == 0)
    {
        if(*year % 100 == 0)
        {
            if(*year % 400 == 0)
            printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year);
            else
            printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
        }
        else
        printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year);
    }
    else
    printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);

   return 0;
}



int main()
{

    printf("What year?\n");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    leapOrNot(year);
    return 0;
}
```

When I input any number, it will check if it's a leap year or not, but instead of saying " is a leap year." or " is not a leap year.", it says "4225408 is a leap year" or "4225408 is not a leap year."

Here are 2 images that show my problem.

[image][image]

What's causing this? I even tried using long data type and I still have the same problem.

Comment: This call  scanf("%d", &year); does not make sense because year is an array. Either declare year as a scalar object or write     scanf("%d", year);
    leapOrNot(); This call leapOrNot(year); in any case does not make sense because the function does not have a parameter.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong here.  Why is `year` an array.  How are you passing `year` to `leapOrNot`?  Implicit `int`?

Comment: Well you probably wanted "2020 is a leap year" or "2020 is not a leap year". What the number `4225408` represents is an address to year[] buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Using array for a 4 digit number is useless. Just integer is enough. Also no need for pointers. Your version prirnt the adress of the array.
That should work

```
int leapOrNot(int year)
{

    if(year % 4 == 0)
    {
        if(year % 100 == 0)
        {
            if(year % 400 == 0)
            printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year);
            else
            printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
        }
        else
        printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year);
    }
    else
    printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);

    return 0;
}


int main()
{  
    int year;
    printf("What year?\n");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    leapOrNot(year);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you change? Why does that fix the problem? What was previously wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year);
```

Changing `year` to `*year` will probably solve this issue, but it seems strange to use an array of ints for this.

The reason why this number is being printed is because `year` is an array, and using `year` actually returns the address of the start of this array. Your code might work(and probably throws a few warnings in the process) but I guess not as you intended. `Scanf` works here because it reads 4 bytes(%d) and writes in into the array first 4 bytes, which means the first cell. though It is clearer to write &year[0].

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems. First, your 'year' is sometimes used as variable

```c
scanf("%d", &year);
```

and sometimes as array/pointer

```c
if(*year % 4 == 0)
```

In your situation, you should probably change it to a standard variable, it means removes [30] from

```c
int year[30];
```

and then remove all dereferences ( '*' sign from *year ). [Read something about pointers in C](https://www.studytonight.com/c/pointers-with-array.php).
Second, you pass year as an argument to leapOrNot() although year is global variable accessible in this function and is not even expected as function parametr. [Read something about global variables](https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/local-global-and-static-variables-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `leapOrNot` does not have a parameter

```
int leapOrNot()
{
   //...
   return 0;
}
```

So in any case independent on how the variable year is declared this call

```
leapOrNot(year);
```

does not make sense.

The function depends on the global array

```
int year[30];
```

and uses its first element by means of the expression `*year`.

Thus for example statements like this

```
printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year);
```

within the function are incorrect. You have to write

```
printf("%d is a leap year.\n", *year);
```

or

```
printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year[0]);
```

So to enter a value for the first element of the array you have to write

```
scanf("%d", year);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%d", &year);
```

There is no great sense to define the function such a way. Also the return type `int` of the function does not have any meaning.

The function could be defined at least like

```
int leapOrNot( unsigned int year )
{
    return ( year % 400 == 0 ) || ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int leapOrNot( unsigned int year )
{
    return ( year % 400 == 0 ) || ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 );
}

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int year = 0;
    
    printf( "What year? " ); 
    scanf( "%u", &year );
    
    printf( "%u is %sa leap year.\n", year, leapOrNot( year ) ? "" : "not " );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problems start here:

```
int year[30];
```

You've declared `year` as a *30-element array* of `int`, which is causing problems here:

```
scanf("%d", &year);
```

and here:

```
if(*year % 4 == 0)
{
    if(*year % 100 == 0)
    {
        if(*year % 400 == 0)
        printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year);
        else
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
    }
    else
    printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year);
}
else
printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
```

I'm not sure why you think you need an array here - you're not storing individual digits to each array element.  A single `int` can store values in *at least* the range `[-32767..32767]`.

So let's start with the `scanf` problem:

```
scanf("%d", &year);
```

The `%d` conversion specifier in a `scanf` call expects its corresponding argument to have type `int *` (pointer to `int`), but what you're passing is a `int (*)[30]` (pointer to 30-element array of `int`).  This results in *undefined behavior* - the compiler isn't required to issue a warning, and weird things can happen at runtime.  An integer value *may* be read in to the first element of `year`, or it may not<sup>1</sup>.

Now for the `leapOrNot` function:

```
    if(*year % 4 == 0)
```

Note that `*year` is equivalent to `year[0]` - this will *just happen to work* assuming you've correctly read an integer value into `year[0]` (which you're not guaranteed to have, as per the discussion above).

But this definitely won't work:

```
printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year);
```

In the `printf` call, `%d` expects its corresponding argument to have type `int`, but `year` has type `int [30]`.  In circumstances like this, an expression of array type "decays" into an expression of pointer type (in this case `int *`), and the value of the expression is the address of the first element.  So you're trying to print the *address* of `year[0]`, not the value contained in it.  But again, since the type of the argument (`int *`) doesn't match what the conversion specifier expects (`int`), the behavior is undefined and the output could be quite literally anything.  It *may* be the address of the first element of the array (formatted as a decimal integer), or it may be something else.

The *minimal* amount of work you need to do in order to fix this is to change the declaration of `year` to

```
int year;
```

and to change all instances of `*year` in `leapOrNot` to just `year`.

However, it would be better to declare `year` in `main` and pass it as an *argument* to `leapOrNot`:

```
int leapOrNot( int year )
{
  // test year
}

int main( void )
{
  int year;

  // read year as before

  leapOrNot( year );
  ...
}
```

An even better change would be to have `leapOrNot` *just* perform the test and return a true or false value, and leave the output to `main`:

```
int leapOrNot( year )
{
  int result = (year % 4 == 0);     // result = true if year is divisible by 4
  if ( result && year % 100 == 0 )  // if year is divisible by 4 and 100
    result = (year % 400 == 0);     // result = true if year is divisible by 400
  return result;
}

int main( void )
{
  int year;
  scanf( "%d", &year );
  if ( leapOrNot( year ) )
    printf ( "%d is a leap year\n", year );
  else
    printf( "%d is NOT a leap year\n", year );
}
```

You want each of your functions to do a single, well-defined thing - note that in this particular case it results in fewer lines of code, mostly by removing redundant output statements.

`leapOrNot` may look a little terse and weird, but it's perfectly valid - you can assign the result of a relational or logical expression to a variable, so basically you can replace

```
if ( a < b && c )
  flag = 1;
else
  flag = 0;
```

with

```
flag = a < b && c;
```

Some people find the second form difficult to read and prefer using the `if-else` form, which is perfectly fine.  I just wanted to point out that this other form exists, and I *personally* find that it can declutter code and make the overall structure of it easier to follow.

---

1. Because of the array decay rule I describe when talking about the `printf` call, this `scanf` call would have worked *just fine* if you had written `scanf( "%d", year );` - the expression `year` would "decay" from type `int [30]` to `int *` and its value would have been the address of `year[0]`.  

   But again, the best course of action is to declare `year` as a plain `int`, not as an array.

Answer (score 0):

As what has been mentioned so far, it is unnecessary for you to make the `year` an array. Your code is simple and straightforward, hence do not require any arrays as it just needs a variable to store the value of the user input.

Just by removing the array and the pointers:

```
int year;


int leapOrNot()
{


    if(year % 4 == 0)
    {
        if(year % 100 == 0)
        {
            if(year % 400 == 0)
            printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year);
            else
            printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
        }
        else
        printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year);
    }
    else
    printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);

   return 0;
}



int main()
{

    printf("What year?\n");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    leapOrNot(year);
    return 0;
}
```